# What takes less time to complete, comparing two variables, or assigning a new value to a variable?

Tags: performance, optimization, logic

Basically what I'm saying is, which operation takes less time to complete? I know the time it takes to complete 1 of these operations is too fast to measure, but I would assume that there would be some way to explain what happens that could explain which one is faster.

Also, I would assume that comparing two variables would be more taxing on the CPU and assigning a value would be more RAM taxing. Is that correct?

Comment: It is far too complicated, and there are far too many factors to cover adequately in a StackOverflow answer.  It would be difficult even if you restricted your self to a specific language, a specific compiler, a specific hardware platform AND a single specific (realistic) example.

Comment: For a start, neither of the operations you are talking about *necessarily* involve main memory at all.  It could all be register to register operations, or operations involving the fast RAM caches.  The distinction between processor and memory is not clear cut in a modern computer design.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

In American football, this would be like asking which is faster:

1. A running play?
2. A passing play?

It's too vague, too general to have any kind of sensible answer.